# PHP filter_var function outputs nothing

Tags: php, function, filter-var

I have the following code:

```
$email = 'test@example.com';
echo $email.'<br>';
echo filter_var('test@example.com',FILTER_SANITZE_EMAIL).' SANITIZED-EMAIL';
```

and it the output is as follows:

```
test@example.com
SANITIZED-EMAIL
```

Clearly the email is completely turned into an empty string. Similarly the `filter_var` with `FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING` does the same thing. What am I missing here?

Comment: didn't you mean `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` instead of `FILTER_SANITZE_EMAIL` (missing a `I` there)

Comment: your code should have thrown an undefined constant. You should be including `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script. of course after `<?php` ;)

Comment: Thank you Bilal. Yes that was the error I couldn't pick. It works as it should now.

Answer (score 2):

Your code does give errors:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant FILTER_SANITZE_EMAIL - assumed
>   'FILTER_SANITZE_EMAIL' in /var/www/html/test.php on line 4
>
> Warning: filter_var() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in
>   /var/www/html/test.php on line 4 SANITIZED-EMAIL

It has to be `FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL` not `FILTER_SANITZE_EMAIL` - so it's just a typo.

Comment: probably you should flag this question as a typo. ;)

Comment: @Akintunde-Rotimi: I don't have the option, I can flag, but there is no option for a "typo" ;)

Comment: @maio290 you can flag as `"should be closed"`, then select `"off-topic"`, then you can select `"problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error"`